# python x86 ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, windows-7-x64, dllimport, anaconda

I have system with win7 x64 and code which worked well before with Anaconda2-2.4.0-Windows-**x86**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

But now I get:

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.py", line 1
2, in <module>
    from .base import LinearRegression
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 28, i
n <module>
    from ..utils import as_float_array, check_array, check_X_y
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 16, in <
module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, i
n <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import in1d
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in <mo
dule>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 11
3, in <module>
    from .matfuncs import *
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py", line 19
, in <module>
    import scipy.misc
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 49, in <mod
ule>
    from scipy.special import comb, factorial, factorial2, factorialk
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 601, in
<module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Yesterday, I have installed [software](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81_(%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%9F%D0%A0)) which brings some python with itself and look like does something else during installation.
In Dependency walker I see following picture:

[image]

I have installed Anaconda2-2.4.0-Windows-x86_**64** and in this python version all works fine.

Could you please help me to understand what has been changed in system and how I can fix it?(I have completely remove installed software but it does not help)

Comment: You may want to be specific. What exactly did you do to install/uninstall?

Comment: I have added link to wiki page of software. Unfortunately this page does bot have English variant as this sw product is used in Russia only.